# Build dataset based on transactions

Tags: r, data-manipulation, transactional

When I search for building datasets using transaction activity I can only find message boards where it deconstructs the dataset to transactions and not the other way around. What I am trying to do is create a function to build a dataset based on current inventory and any recent transaction activity. I have tried merging the 2 datasets and using cumulative sum, but it doesn't seem to work. Ultimately, I am looking to rollforward quantities for each item and then adjust them by the amounts listed in the trans table.

```
trans <- data.frame(day = c(3,3),
                id = c('a','b'),
                qty = c(10,-20))
inventory <- data.frame(day = c(1,1),
                    id = c('a','b'),
                    qty = c(10,20))
##Desired output
output <- data.frame(day = c(1,1,2,2,3),
                 id = c('a','b','a','b','a'),
                 qty = c(10,20,10,20,20))
```

Comment: where does day 2 come from in your output?

Comment: Day 2 is just a carry foward from day 1 since there was no transaction. Day 3 is the value of day 2 plus the transactions. I omitted b on day 3 in the output since it would be zero, but a value is also workable

Answer (score 0):

First create the vectors the way you want...

```
ts <- rep(seq(min(inventory$day),max(trans$day)),each = length(unique(inventory$id)))
ids <- rep(inventory$id, length(unique(ts)))
qty <- rep(inventory$qty, length(unique(ts)))
output <- data.frame(day = ts, id = ids)
```

Then merge the transaction data.frame and set all na values to 0

```
transM <- merge(trans,output, all.y = T)
transM$qty[is.na(transM$qty)] <- 0
```

Finally get the result

```
output$qty <- qty + transM$qty
```